# Able to scroll by mouse well but unable to move the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to be able to scroll through the whole page with moving scroll bar but the scroll bar not moving although i able to scroll with mouse well.

My html ：

```
 <div id="mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_1_scrollbar mCS-minimal mCSB_scrollTools_vertical" style="display: block;">
                        <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer" >
                        <div id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                        <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Jquery :

```
(function($){
$(window).load( function() {
    $(".mCSB_draggerContainer").css("height", "1550px");
    $(".mCSB_draggerContainer").css("overflow-y", "hidden");

    $.getScript("//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.7/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js", function () {
        $('mCSB_draggerContainer').mCustomScrollbar({
            theme: "light-3"
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi Morgan, Can you please place this in a JSFiddle and share us a working link to see what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you meant to set the height and overflow? Maybe that's messing up the script...